# AlarmManager to simply update data without waking up screen

Tags: android, alarmmanager

AlarmManager to simply update data without waking up screen

How do I do this ?? 
I want to update my Call and Data usages values in background at intervals without waking up my display screen

Comment: I don't get it, yes use `AlarmManager` for the this kind of purposes.

Comment: alarms don't wake up the sceen, they wake up the device from sleep.  the screen can stay off while that happens.

Comment: @paul -
Ok maybe I did some mistake in my code . ill try it again and get back .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of alarmmanager write a service. It will work at background. I think these links will help you.
http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidServices/article.html
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

Answer (score 0):

The best was to achieve this is by running a CountDownTimer or run a background thread in a service.

Comment: But it is said if used by following way it gets killed by system.
I need it to run 24x7

Comment: Run a background thread with infinite loop in a service. So that it wont get killed. Also you start your service when the device is powered on by RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry my fault . call to gui was accidently put in service . ie service calls main page . :(
got it solved

new to android